# pass all select values to php

Tags: php, jquery

I have one select box:

```
<select name="sub_selected" class="bmarks" id="sub_selected" 
style="width:400px" size="5">
            <option value="1">first value</option>
            <option value="2">second value</option>
            <option value="4">other vale</option>
                                  </select>
```

I want to pass all values to php.

I write the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$('#sub_selected').each(function(i, selected){
        foo[i] = $(selected).val();

                var title     = $('#prop_tile').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_process.php",
                data: "title="+ title +"& stages="+ foo,
                success: function(html){
                if (html==1){
                $('div.saving').hide();
                $('div.success').fadeIn();
                }else {
                $('div.saving').hide();
                $('div.nosuccess').fadeIn();
                }

                }
                });
```

I want to submit all values of select box to php to store in mysql, preferably in this format (1,2,4).

Thanks

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, may I ask why? What will the script do if all the values are selected, rather than the one value that would normally be submitted?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about jquery but it seems to me you may be able to resolve your issue purely at the HTML level, assuming your jquery simply submits the form that contains your `<select>` tag. The way `<select>` behaves is that the browser will only submit data in the post that is selected. If the options are not highlighted, they won't be sent to the server in your `POST`.

You may be able to resolve it as follows; First of all, your `<select>` needs the `multiple="multiple"` attribute so that more than one element can be selected. Secondly, add the `selected="selected"` attribute to each of the `<option>` tags. And lastly, if you don't want the user to unselect any of the options prior to form submission, add the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the `<select>` tag.

UPDATE: You may also want to change the `name="sub_selected"` to `name="sub_selected[]"` so that you can receive the value as an array on the PHP side. You'll need to adjust your jquery references of `sub_selected` to `sub_selected[]`.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Actually, the select elements will only come into PHP as an array if the name attribute of the select tag ends with [].

Answer (score 0):

If you really want ALL of them, then don't do it that way. Get them in PHP the same way you got them to display the select options.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with jquery, here is the simple/correct way to do it:

```
// I'm not sure what the '#prop_tile' element is so I didn't 
// include it for this example
var all_vals = new Array; 
$('#sub_selected option').each(function() {
    all_vals.push($(this).val());
});
$.post('add_process.php', { stages:all_vals }, function(html) {
    $('div.saving').hide();
    $('div.success').fadeIn();
},'html');
```

On the receiving end, you can do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['all_vals'])) {
    $all_vals = $_POST['all_vals'];
    // $all_vals is now an array = [1,2,4]
}
?>
```

**NOTE**: It would be nice if you disclosed more details about why you would want to do this because, skin deep, it seems like a silly thing to do.